# How to change the selected color of RadCalendar in Windows-Phone?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, telerik, windows-phone-7.1

I am using the Telerik's RadCalendar control for my WindowsPhone application. I want to change the SelectedDate's Background color in RadCalendar of WindowsPhone... Is there any way to change this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the SelectedDay's properties through using a Special Template. Here is a sample data template for a day:

```
<telerikInput:RadCalendar>
  <telerikInput:RadCalendar.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DetailText}" FontSize="7" MaxHeight="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-2,0,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </telerikInput:RadCalendar.ItemTemplate>
</telerikInput:RadCalendar>
```

Example of a special template for weekends

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:WeekendDaySelector x:Key="WeekendDaySelector">
    <local:WeekendDaySelector.SpecialTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="5">
          <Image Source="/Calendar/Images/SpecialDay.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" x:Name="TextPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </local:WeekendDaySelector.SpecialTemplate>
  </local:WeekendDaySelector>
</UserControl.Resources>

<telerikInput:RadCalendar ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource WeekendDaySelector}" />
```

Now the template selector

```
public class WeekendDaySelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SpecialTemplate
    {
        get;
          set;
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        CalendarButtonContentInfo info = item as CalendarButtonContentInfo;
          CalendarButton button = container as CalendarButton;
          if (!button.IsFromCurrentView) return null;
          if (info.Date == null) return null;
          if (info.Date.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
              info.Date.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
          {
               return SpecialTemplate;
          }
          return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

You can learn more in [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/windows-phone/calendar/selected-date-indicator.aspx).